# Increase submenu width

Tags: css

I stuck with my submenu dropdown menu... I need increase width of my submenu but i can´t because it increase the menu to and the submenu... they are dependent and i need them independent

```
.fancyNav{
/* Affects the UL element */
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
z-index:999;
}
.fancyNav li{
/* Specifying a fallback color and we define CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */

 background: #CCC;
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=10);
   opacity:.7;

border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);

/* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */



position:relative;

float: left;
list-style: none;
}

.fancyNav li:after{
    content:'.';
text-indent:-9999px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0; 
opacity:0;
z-index:1;
/* Gradients! */

background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(168,168,168,0)), to(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)));

background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,1));

background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));

/* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */

box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

/* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */

-moz-transition:0.25s all;
-webkit-transition:0.25s all;
-o-transition:0.25s all;
transition:0.25s all;}

/* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */



.fancyNav li:first-child:after,
 .fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after{
box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

-moz-transition:0.25s all;
-webkit-transition:0.25s all;
-o-transition:0.25s all;
transition:0.25s all;}

 /* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */



.fancyNav li:first-child:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after{
box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

}

.fancyNav li:last-child{
}

/* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */

.fancyNav li:last-child:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:last-child:after{
box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
}
.fancyNav li:hover:after,
.fancyNav li.selected:after,
.fancyNav li:target:after{
/* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
opacity:1;
 }

.fancyNav:hover li.selected:after,
.fancyNav:hover li:target:after{
/* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
opacity:0;
}
.fancyNav li.selected:hover:after,
.fancyNav li:target:hover:after{
opacity:1 !important;

}
/* Styling the anchor elements */
.menudiv{
position:fixed;
z-index:999;
width:951px;
margin-left:-476px;
left:50%;
}
.menlog{
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;

}
.menlog2{
padding:12px 15px 15px;

}
.corrente{
   background-color:white;
padding:12px 15px 15px;
}
.corrente3{
}
.fancyNav li a{
color: #000000;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
z-index:2;
text-decoration:none !important;
white-space:nowrap;

}
.fancyNav a.homeIcon{
background:url('../img/home.png') no-repeat center center;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: -9999px;
}


nav{
display: block;
text-align: center;

}
a, a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
color:#54a6de;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

the submenu code is that

```
ul ul li{
    float:none !important;
display: block;
padding: 2px;
}
ul ul{
display:none;
position:relative;    /* updated */
z-index:2;            /* updated */
}
ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
```

HTML Code,

```
<nav><ul class="fancyNav">
<li id="quemsomos" class="menlog"><a href="index.php"><img src="imgs/Logo.png"  width="37" height="45" /></a></li>
<li id="quemsomos"><a href="quemsomos.php?web=1"><font face="din" size="4">QUEM SOMOS</font></a>

  <!--start of sub menu-->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test DropDown</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test DropDown</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test DropDown</a></li>
  </ul>
<!--end of sub menu-->

</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: make a jsfiddle, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css

```
ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
position:absolute
}
```

Thanks

check this http://jsfiddle.net/RHCn7/4/

Comment: Thanks works fine... can you remove the border show in the right of subitem? and add a background to the submenu?

Comment: Thanks works fine... can you remove the border show in the right of subitem? and add a background to the submenu?

Comment: @Ricardo  Pleae check this http://jsfiddle.net/RHCn7/1/ . And  Please accept my answer by click the Tick mark